# How to login in java using username and password reading from a textfile with ten records?

Tags: java, tokenize

The message should also show the number of login attempts the user made. If the user reached the maximum number of attempts, the program will be terminated indicated by a message dialog showing “Number of Attempts exceeded. Program Terminated”.
My code accepts the username and password if there is only one password and one username in the textfile. How to scan all of the 10 data in the textfile and if it matches the user's input it will grant access?

My textfile looks like this:

```
    [awe1,pass1]
    [awe2,pass2]
    [awe3,pass3]
    [awe4,pass4]
    [awe5,pass5]
    [awe6,pass6]
    [awe7,pass7]
    [awe8,pass8]
    [awe9,pass9]
    [awe10,pass10]
```

Readfile:

```
private static  String ReadFile(){
        String line=null;
        String text="";
        try{

            FileReader filereader=new FileReader(new File("MyLoginData.txt"));
             //FileReader filereader=new FileReader(new File(path));
            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(filereader);
            while((line=bf.readLine()) !=null){
                text=text+line;

            }
            bf.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;

    }


   public void PassWordFrame()
   {

      btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //Execute when button is pressed
                String info = ReadFile();
                System.out.println(info);
                String[] split = info.split(",");
                String uname=split[0];
                String pass =split[1];

                if(txtUsername.getText().equals(uname) && txtPassword.getText().equals(pass)){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Access granted", "Status", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Access Denied", "Status", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }); 

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way you can read file at that time you can check for username and password

```
while ((line= br.readLine()) !=null) {

// Split line by a whitespace character
// split[0] <- username
// split[1] <- password

line = line.replace("[","").replace("]","");
String[] split =line .split(",");

if (user.equals(split[0]) && pass.equals(split[1])) {

    //redirect where you want
    // You found the user, exit the loop
    break;
 }
}
```

Use one `int count` for storing attempts after exceed attempt show message and terminate the program.

Comment: what is  menu = new Mainemenu();
    menu.AdminMenu();??

Comment: just redirect where u want